# WCF Service Address on Azure Website

Tags: wcf, azure-web-app-service, azureservicebus

I am planning to run a WCF service with netTcpRelayBinding on azure website.

One of the interesting feature that azure website allows is to update the appsettings & swap between live and staging environment.

The problem that I am having is how can I change the address of service bus address when I swap from staging to production and vice versa. I think one way to achieve is by having the service address in appsettings.

Note: I can achieve this with web.config transform and redeployment. However we are trying to avoid redeployment.

The problem with example:

```
<services>
  <service name="Hwo.LocationService.Wcf.HotelLocationService">
    <endpoint                   address="sb://staging.servicebus.windows.net/IHotelLocationService"
              binding="netTcpRelayBinding" 
              contract="Hwo.ProductInterface.Common.Azure.Contracts.IHotelLocationService"
              name="HotelLocationServiceEndPoint" />
  </service>
```

...

As it can seen above, the address is pointing to staging environment. But when we swap that that application in production , the address wont change. We would like to change that endpoint address when we swap.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With advise from Will, I managed to write service host factory which solves the problem the perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        var serviceEndpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType.GetInterfaces().First(),
            new NetTcpRelayBinding("netTcpRelayBinding"),
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBus.Address"] + serviceType.Name);
        serviceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(
            new TransportClientEndpointBehavior(
                TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBus.Key"],
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBus.Value"])));
        return serviceHost;
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Due to it can swap the App settings, so I suggest you can write your Address value into App settings in web.config file. Meanwhile, you need read the address value and set it as your service's endpoint in your code. If you swap the slots, you just modify the App Setting on the Azure portal.

Read config:

```
WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configFile"]
```

Modify the settings:

[image]

**[Update]**
Please refer to this document to dynamically set your endpoint on different enviroment(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/06/13/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory/)

Comment: I understood the first bit, could you please elaborate on second bit of your answer. 
Meanwhile, you need read the address value and set it as your service's endpoint in your code. If you swap the slots, you just modify the App Setting on the Azure portal.

Read config:

WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configFile"]  

Much appreciated.

Comment: I means that we can get the endpoint value using the code like 'WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configFile"]'. When you swap sites, you just changed the App Settings on Azure portal, it is not necessary to redeploy.

Comment: Ok I understand that now. The problem is that I wont be able to bind  the address to a WCF service (unless i runs the application as a console). I prefer to run it under IIS.

Comment: Like this scenario, I recommend you can use 'Service HostFactory'  (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/06/13/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory/) to dynamically set Endpoints.

Comment: Yea I think I will give that a go. Thanks Will